# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS jacsonannotation

Tags: java, jackson, annotations

I am using the Emoji4j  - I have included the below libs in the classpath.

[image: Libraries added to the Projects]

When I run this code:

```
    String message = sCurrentLine.split(",")[6];
            String[] words = message.split(" ");
            for (String s : words) {
                System.out.println(s);
                System.out.print( " Have " +EmojiUtils.isEmoji(s)+  " 
   Emojis" );
    }
```

It gives me the below error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: USE_DEFAULTS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Value.<clinit> 
    (JsonInclude.java:247)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.ConfigOverrides.<init> 
    (ConfigOverrides.java:55)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init> 
    (ObjectMapper.java:564)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init> 
    (ObjectMapper.java:480)
    at emoji4j.EmojiManager.<clinit>(EmojiManager.java:23)
    at emoji4j.EmojiUtils.getEmoji(EmojiUtils.java:39)
    at emoji4j.EmojiUtils.isEmoji(EmojiUtils.java:60)
    at com.isme.test.EmojiTest.main(EmojiTest.java:39)
```

Answer (score 6):

That sounds like multiple versions of the `JsonInclude.Include` inner enum class.  This is in the `jackson-annotations.jar` which shows twice in the excerpt of the classpath above.

Browsing around suggests both the `JsonInclude.Value` inner class and `JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS` got added somewhere between Jackson 2.5 and 2.6.

Emoji4j clearly needs the `JsonInclude.Value` inner class, which in turn depends on `JsonInclude.Include.USE_DEFAULTS`.  If an older version of `JsonInclude.Include` is being loaded, `USE_DEFAULTS` will be missing.